# Microsoft Word Complains me this phrase is wrong - Is it right?

Tags: phrases, sentence

> A programming craftsman having hands on knowledge in Web development
>   (Including user interaction), Software Development Life cycle, and
>   database programming

How should the sentence be formed so that it is correct( I am not sure this is wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various issues here which may raise flags such as:

1. No finite verb
2. No full stop
3. An idiosyncratic use of capital letters such as "Including" in the middle of the phrase

Comment: 4. A missing hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is not a sentence, as it contains no [finite verb](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/finite?q=finite). You have written an explanation of someone's qualifications on a specific branch of knowledge, similar to the much shorter (Name,) Teacher with MA in Linguistics. Word doesn't recognise these strings as sentences, although they aren't wrong. If you want to convert it into a sentence, it would be something like:

*He is/I am a programming craftsman with hands on knowledge...*

Answer (score 1):

This is not a sentence but a phrase, specifically a Noun Phrase.

I suspect that the error message you are being given in Word would be 'fragment'; am I right?

In order for this to be a complete sentence, you require a verb. Upon adding the verb, this phrase could then be made either the subject or object of your sentence. I assume you want the following:

I am a programming...

That said, there is nothing wrong with using phrases as long as they make sense in context. If you are listing attributes, say for a CV, then bullet-pointed phrases like this are normal.